# Deleting a node from linked list using `delete`

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, delete-operator

Here is a part of code for deleting an element from the tail a singly Linked List:

```
int SLList::deleteFromTail()
{
    int el = tail->info;

    //if the list has only one element
    if(head == tail) {
        delete head;
        head = tail = 0;
    }
    else {
        //some code here...
    }

    return el
}
```

Here `head` and `tail` are pointers to first and last element of LL, respectively.

In the `if` block above after `delete head` we are setting `head = tail = 0`.

But **after we have deleted `head`, how can we set it's value to something?** (`NULL` in this case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Head is a `pointer`. You are deleting an `object` pointed by the `pointer`, not the `pointer` itself

Consider this example:

```
Foo *foo = new Foo(); //foo does not store Foo object. Just an adress of created object.
//do some stuff
delete foo; //object is deleted
foo = new Foo(); //create another Foo and make foo point to it
```

**EDIT** 
A pointer is just an adress ob an object. When you write `delete head` you delete the object pointed by head, but even after deletion `head pointer` will point to the same place as before. But dereferencing it (e.g. `*head`) will cause problems.

Comment: when I say `delete head` , am I not deleting the pointer itself and `not` the object pointed by it? Wouldn't the object pointed by it be `*head`?

Comment: `new` returns a pointer, and `delete` wants that pointer back.

Answer (score 1):

After deleted the head, Create new object and **assign the address** of the object **to head**

```
head = addressOfNewObject;
```